# Testing multiple ML models - Dead Kernel Everytime

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The number of rows is close to 1 million. I define the models I want to test as such

```
X = df_final[['short_description', 'details', 'root_cause']]
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 0)

tfidf_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf' ,TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500, ngram_range=(1, 3), stop_words = 'english', strip_accents= 'ascii',))])

countvec_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('countvec' ,CountVectorizer(max_features=1500, ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words = 'english', strip_accents= 'ascii', binary = True))])


preprocessor_pipeline = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
    ('short_description', countvec_pipeline,'short_description'),
    ('details', tfidf_pipeline,'details'),
    ('root_cause', countvec_pipeline, 'root_cause'),
])

models = [
    ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, 
                                  max_depth=3, 
                                  random_state=0,
                                  n_jobs = -1)),
    ('svc',LinearSVC()),
    ('nb', MultinomialNB()),
    ('lr', LogisticRegression(random_state=0, 
                              solver = 'saga', 
                              n_jobs = -1))
]
```

I then do a `fit_transform` as so

```
X_prepped = preprocessor_pipeline.fit_transform(X)
```

The below part is where my kernel once it hits the first model being random forest it breaks.

```
for model_name, model in models:
    print(model_name)
    results_dict = cross_validate(model, X_prepped, labels, cv = cv, scoring = 'accuracy', return_train_score = True)
    results_df = pd.DataFrame(results_dict)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: your  ('nb', MultinomialNB()), classifier is failing.  Try running it by itself in the pipeline .  I tested RandomForestClassifier and LogisticRegression and they worked.

Comment: ('svc',LinearSVC()) works also.  It seems like RandomForestClassifier will be the best choice

Comment: use   ('lr', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))  : OneVsRestClassifier  from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

Comment: Include MaxAbsScaler for the logistic regression and its accuracy will improve.  ('scale', MaxAbsScaler()),
        ('lr', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(C=100)))

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline,  FeatureUnion, make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import nltk  
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import     CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2, SelectKBest
 import spacy
 from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler

 df=pd.read_csv('input_data.csv')

 NUMERIC=['Cost','Field2']
 TEXT=['Text1', 'Text2']


 def combine_text_columns(data_frame, text_labels=TEXT):
    """ converts all text in each row of data_frame to single vector """
    #to_drop = set(to_drop) & set(data_frame.columns.tolist())
    #text_dta=data_frame.drop(to_drop,axis=1)

    text_data =data_frame[text_labels]
 
    # Replace nans with blanks
    text_data.fillna("",inplace=True)

# Join all text items in a row that have a space in between
return text_data.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x), axis=1)

 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
 stopwords=spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
 chi_k = 300
 # Create the token pattern: TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC
 TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC = '[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=\\s+)'


 get_text_data = FunctionTransformer(combine_text_columns,validate=False)

 # Preprocess the numeric data: get_numeric_data
 get_numeric_data = FunctionTransformer(lambda x:    x[NUMERIC], validate=False)

  pl = Pipeline([
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list = [
            ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', get_numeric_data),
                ('imputer', SimpleImputer())
            ])),
            ('text_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', get_text_data),
                ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
                    #('vectorizer',CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords,token_pattern=TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC, ngram_range=(1,2))),('dim_red', SelectKBest(chi2, chi_k))
            ]))
         ]
    )),
    ('scale', MaxAbsScaler()),
    #('svc',LinearSVC())
    #('nb', MultinomialNB()),
    #('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=15)))
    ('lr', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(C=100)))
  ])

  TARGET=['IsApartment']    
  sc_X = StandardScaler()
   encoder=LabelEncoder()
   label_enc=pd.Series(encoder.fit_transform(df['OpportunityName']))

   NUMERIC2=[]
   [NUMERIC2.append(x) for x in NUMERIC]
   NUMERIC2.append('opportunityName_enc')
   X2=df[NUMERIC]
   X2=pd.concat([X2,label_enc],axis=1)

   X2 = pd.DataFrame(sc_X.fit_transform(X2),columns=NUMERIC2)
   X=pd.concat([X,X2],axis=1)
   X=pd.concat([X,df[TEXT]],axis=1)
   y=df[TARGET]

   X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=.3, random_state=42)

 pl.fit(X_train,y_train)
 predictions=pl.predict(X_train)
 accuracy = pl.score(X_train, y_train)
 print("\nAccuracy on sample data - numeric, no nans:{:.2f}% ".format(accuracy))
 ytrain_pred_probas = pl.predict_proba(X_train)[:, 1]        
 # prob of predict as 1
 fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_train, ytrain_pred_probas)   # precision_recall_curve
 roc = pd.DataFrame({'FPR':fpr,'TPR':tpr,'Thresholds':thresholds})
 _ = plt.figure()
 plt.plot(roc.FPR, roc.TPR)
 plt.axvline(0.1, color = '#00C851', linestyle = '--')
 plt.xlabel("FPR")
 plt.ylabel("TPR")
```